# Maven + weblogic

Tags: java, maven, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

I have EJB projects
With the following pom

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>gerenciador.service</groupId>
                <artifactId>GerenciadorService</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>GerenciadorService-${project.version}.jar</bundleFileName>
                <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
            </ejbModule>
            <jarModule> 
                <groupId>gerenciador.dao.client</groupId> 
                <artifactId>GerenciadorDaoClient</artifactId> 
                <bundleFileName>GerenciadorDaoClient-${project.version}.jar</bundleFileName>
                <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
            </jarModule> 
        </modules>

        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I install my EAR is created correctly

but the following error is occurring

```
<06/12/2013 15h46min34s BRST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.init(EJBModule.java:301)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:74)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:312)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find ejb-jar with uri GerenciadorService.jar in ear at C:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\GerenciadorServiceEAR\beadep\base_domain\GerenciadorServiceEAR
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EJBJar.<init>(EJBJar.java:72)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.init(EJBModule.java:275)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:74)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

If I enter this path, because it is not GerenciadorService.jar maven creates GerenciadorService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Missing some configuration in my pom?

The maven is generating this application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application version="6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <display-name>GerenciadorServiceEAR</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>GerenciadorService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What does your application.xml of the EAR module say? Do you maintain this yourself or does Maven generate it for you?

Comment: The maven is generating


`<application version="6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<display-name>GerenciadorServiceEAR</display-name>
<module>
<ejb>GerenciadorService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>
<library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>
</application>`

sorry for the code, that this is not indented

Comment: You can delete the comment and edit your question & add it there, it's much cleaner that way and the norm on this site is to put all data in question for easier readability.